# how to get SMS delivery in my C# Application?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I want to send SMS with C# in my Windows Mobile (6.1) and get the delivery report too.

I know I can send SMS with below code:

```
string str = "hello world";
            SmsMessage sms = new SmsMessage("09******", str);
            sms.Send();
```

and I know i can get the delivery report with below code:

```
  sms.RequestDeliveryReport = true or false;
```

but in this way I just see notification and I need to handle it in my program , not just notification.

I need to see the Message status too. For eg:

SMS state like sent successfully or no GSM Antena and ....so on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least i found a solution.

when you try below code :

```
 sms.RequestDeliveryReport = true;
```

C# will give you a event that notify to you that your last message have been received.
it will give it to you like a new message.

for SMS Status , you get exception if phone can not send Message.